# SwitchPreference not switching visibly (no color switch, no animation) API >=23

Tags: java, android, material-design, androidx

So I recently made a small update for my app and users on older APIs (equal lower 23) complained that the PreferenceSwitch work for the logic but there is no visible sign it was switched. API over 24 is working fine.

Even if I preset the Switches and reload the Fragment the switches are not set visibly.

I would like to fix this but I have no clue why this bug appears.

I am using takisoft preferencex and com.takisoft.preferencex.PreferenceFragmentCompat
But a quick change to the official one didnt work, same behavior

I searched online and on github but I couldnt come up with a solution.

Edit: I just installed my old version on an Emulator running API 23 and the switches are still not working.

A small sample of my code:

```
vib.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
           
                if (vibrate) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("vibrate", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.apply();
                    vibrate = sharedPref.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
                    vib.setChecked(vibrate);


                } else {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("vibrate", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.apply();
                    vibrate = sharedPref.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
                    vib.setChecked(vibrate);

                }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it:

I have a base application theme where I had added

`<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceTheme</item>`

This was the problem. What I made now is that deleted this line and I added the following to my Preference Fragment inside the onCreateView

`activity.setTheme(R.style.AppPreferenceTheme);`